# Handling multiple values in a single SSIS Parameter

Tags: ssis, sql-server-2008-r2

I have a SSIS package that runs in SQL 2008 R2.  This package gets it's data from a SQL statement using a parameter that is populated from a variable.  This variable was populated from a separate SQL table.  This works well when the variable contains a single value, like this:

User::MachineWC = "WC1"  (no quotes in db field, just shown for discussion)

```
SELECT TOP 100 [WONumber]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Work Center] = (?)
```

When executed, the question mark is correctly replaced with the single value.  However, I want to use ***multiple values***, via the "IN" syntax, like this:

```
SELECT TOP 100 [WONumber]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Work Center] IN (?)
```

In this case the variable would contain multiple values, like...

User::MachineWC = "WC1,WC2,WC3"

When I do this, it just blows past this data source and no records are returned.  No error message is displayed and there is nothing in the Execution Results tab afterwards indicating any issues.

I realize that the normal SQL syntax should include a single quotation mark when this is called.  In other words, to execute with multiple values, it would look like this in SSMS:

```
SELECT TOP 100 [WONumber]
FROM [MyTable]
WHERE [Work Center] IN ('WC1','WC2','WC3')
```

I have tried to edit the value multiple ways in my table to test this syntax, but the package never finds any records (the above statement does return multiple records in SSMS).  It's almost like SSIS is appending the single quote/appostrophe "automatically", but I can't get the format correct.

I would greatly appreciate any suggestions anyone could give me.
Thank you!

Comment: Haven't found the duplicate yet but this is not possible

Comment: billinkc - The thread you posted looks promising; I didn't see that one when I searched earlier.  I will experiment with that method and post back with the results.  Thank you for your quick reply!